# Get AD Users without LDAP C#

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, active-directory-import

How can i get all active directory users in SharePoint 2010 webpart **without LDAP connection string**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your SharePoint server is running in a different server, then it is not possible. You can get users inside the Active Directory server without LDAP connection like following.

```
using (var directoryInfo = new DirectoryEntry())
            {
                var userFindingfilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
                var userProperties = new string[] { "title", "whenChanged", "displayName", "department", "sAMAccountName", "userPrincipalName", "manager" };
                using (var directoryInfoSearch = new DirectorySearcher(directoryInfo, userFindingfilter, userProperties, SearchScope.Subtree))
                {
                    var directoryEntryUserSearchResults = directoryInfoSearch.FindAll();
                    foreach (SearchResult searchResult in directoryEntryUserSearchResults)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Now when your are in different server, you must specify the **LDAP** connection string, user name & password

```
using (var directoryInfo = new DirectoryEntry(ConnectString, UserName, Password))
            {
                var userFindingfilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))";
                var userProperties = new string[] { "title", "whenChanged", "displayName", "department", "sAMAccountName", "userPrincipalName", "manager" };
                using (var directoryInfoSearch = new DirectorySearcher(directoryInfo, userFindingfilter, userProperties, SearchScope.Subtree))
                {
                    var directoryEntryUserSearchResults = directoryInfoSearch.FindAll();
                    foreach (SearchResult searchResult in directoryEntryUserSearchResults)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to run a LDAP query in .NET.  You can use [DirectorySearcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.aspx) from `System.DirectoryServices` or [SearchRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols.searchrequest.searchrequest.aspx) from `System.DirectoryServices.Protocol`.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomain.com"))
{
    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
    {
        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
        {
            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
        }
    }
}
```